# How do I pass arguments to an event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function object to which I want to pass an argument on click using jquery, but it's not working.

```
<script>
var item=232;
$(function(){
    $('div').click(fn_clik('Mike'))
})

var fn_clik = function(name){
        alert('Name is:' + name + ' item is:' + item)
}
</script>
```

I don't understand the concept behind it. Can anyone please explain where am I going wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1

Comment: First things first. This sample is "wrong" because with `fn_clik('Mike')` you are invoking `fn_clik` on the spot, while what you really want is to arrange for it to be called later. This is crucial in order to understand the possible solutions.

Comment: @tintin Did you find your answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have the function you are calling return a function with the name, passed by argument, in a closure:

```
$('div').click( fn_clik('Mike') );

var fn_clik = function(name){      
     return function() {
         alert('Name is:' + name + ' item is:' + item);
     }
}
```

Or have an anonymous function you pass wrap the original function called with the correct parameter:

```
$('div').click(function () {
    fn_clik('Mike')
});
```

A quick note, in your original code, you were calling the function 'fn_clik' instead of passing it as an object. So your code was evaluating to:

```
$('div').click( undefined );
```

This is because your original 'fn_clik' has no return value;

Comment: `fn_clik()` will be invoked immediately, not when the click is triggered.

Comment: @oGeez And that's fine, because `fn_clik` **returns a function**

Comment: @Ian right you are, I should've been paying more attention.

Comment: Won't it create a new function each click?

Comment: @sp00m No because the .click() function that registers the event handler is only called once.

Comment: While this answer is correct, I think it's horribly confusing for the OPs current level of understanding.

Answer (score 4):

If you write "func(...)" you call your function, you must to juste write function name.

### Without argument

Like this :

```
$('div').click(fn_clik);
```

### With argument

If you want get argument, use anonymous function like this :

```
$('div').click(function () {
    fn_clik('Mike')
});
```

### See *this* and *event* variables.

The *this* variable return element node, and *event* return click event.

```
$("body").click(function (event) {
    if (this == $("body")[0]) {
        alert("self");
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/lotapa/1/edit)

Answer (score 1):

This is hownormally I do ,

```
<script>
    var item=232;
    $(function(){
        $('div').on('click',function(){
            fn_clik('Mike');
        });

    })

    function fn_clik(name){
            alert('Name is:' + name + ' item is:' + item)
    }
</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function and using the return value (undefined) when binding, instead of getting a reference to the function that the event can call.

Wrap the function call in a function expression, so that you get a reference to it:

```
$('div').click(function() { fn_clik('Mike'); });
```

You can also use the [`proxy` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to create a function with the parameter bound to it:

```
$('div').click($.proxy(fn_clik, this, 'Mike'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var item = 232;

$(function(){   
    $('div').click(function(e){fn_click("Mike");});
})

var fn_clik = function(name){      
    alert('Name is:' + name + ' item is:' + item)
}
```